# Draw an ASCII envelope based on size input

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

You want to send an ASCII letter to someone, but you need an envelope to put it in. Your task is to output an envelope given a size as input.

Rules:

- Given positive integer input `i`, your envelope will be `i` characters tall (not counting the top row), and `i*2` characters wide (not counting the side columns). In other words, your envelope will be `i+1` characters tall and `(i*2)+2` characters wide.
- Output **must** be in the form of text, using `\`, `/`, `_`, `|`, and  .
- The flap of the envelope must be on the row above the bottom row of the envelope unless impossible (as with an envelope of size 1).
- Trailing whitespace is allowed.

Example input and output:

```
1
->
 __
|\/|

2
->
 ____
|\__/|
|____|

3
->
 ______
|\    /|
| \__/ |
|______|

4
->
 ________
|\      /|
| \    / |
|  \__/  |
|________|
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so shortest code wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
Ｎθ←×_θ↑θ→Ｐ×_θ↓¿⊖θ«↘⊖θ←¶_»\‖Ｍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xD4IwFIRn@yuaTm2CmxNdWUyEGKIbCcH6kCalhVJwMP72SsFownh337t3oqmsMJXy/qi70WVjewNLe8bR2UrtaHyC2kX4IlsYKClJhHv2D69d0BylZgIa5/LRuKBG5WS3ENu7FUzMU89C1pgmICy0oB3c568Mv9Du2x2gpTHCG4j/mHUcKXRJZveNQA2A14wURfByqBUIl0prjaWMe3/w@0l9AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `i`.

```
←×_θ
```

Draw half of the bottom row of `_`s.

```
↑θ
```

Draw the left column of `|`s.

```
→Ｐ×_θ↓
```

Draw the top row of `_`s.

```
¿⊖θ«
```

If `i` is not `1`, then...

```
↘⊖θ←¶_
```

... draw the `i-1` `\`s on the left and one of the two middle `_`s, ...

```
»\
```

... otherwise overwrite the bottom `_` with a `\`.

```
‖Ｍ
```

Reflect to complete the envelope.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
i'_„|\‚ë2ÊiÍFðI×'\Nǝ}}„\_Ij¤I×©)'|ì®š}º.c
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Uz3@UcO8mphHDbMOrzY63JV5uNft8AbPw9PVY/yOz62tBUrGxHtmHVoCFDq0UlO95vCaQ@uOLqw9tEsv@f9/EwA) or [verify the first few outputs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/qquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4en4uYT@z1SPf9QwrybmUcOsw6v9jA53Zfod7nU7vCHi8HT1GL/jc2trgdIx8RFZh5YAhQ6t1FSvObzm0LqjC2sP7dJL/q9zaJv9fwA).

**Expanation:**

```python
i              # If the (implicit) input is 1:
 '|„|\‚       '#  Push pair of strings ["_","|\"]
ë              # Else:
 2Êi           #  If the (implicit) input is NOT 2:
    ÍF         #   Loop `N` in the range [0,input-2):
      ðI×      #    Push a string with the input amount of spaces
         '\Nǝ '#    Insert a "\" character at index `N`
     }         #   Close the loop
   }           #  Close the inner if-statement
„\_            #  Push string "\_"
   Ij          #  Pad leading spaces until the string is of a length equal to the input
     ¤         #  Push the last character (without popping): "_"
      I×       #  Repeat it the input amount of times as string
        ©      #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
)              #  Wrap all values on the stack into a list
 '|ì          '#  Prepend a "|" in front of each string
    ®š         #  Prepend string `®` to the list
}              # Close the outer if-else statement
 º             # Mirror each inner string
  .c           # Join by newlines and centralize
               # (adding a single leading space to the first "_"-string)
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Congrats on reaching 100k!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>207</s> <s>181</s> <s>180</s> <s>177</s> <s>146</s> 130 bytes

```python
lambda i,u="__",b=" ":b+u*i+"".join(f"\n|{b*x}\{(b*(i*2+~x*2),u)[x==i-2]}/{b*x}|"for x in range(i-1))+("\n|\/|",f"\n|{u*i}|")[i>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TczdCoIwGIDh865ifEf7M3F2FKwbcSKOWn1hU0RhoXbry4rAs/fg4e2ew631eXTaxKZ@2HNNUI4aqgqk1UDgaMXIUQDs7y166sD4ebI8LGaillPkSrwCV0yOrAhaY6LKJf2CGVzbk0DQk7721wvFJGNM0M/BpDPI32u9r5QVeMrK2PXoB@roCnf/VpvON31gLL4B)

**To 181 bytes:** Golfed the code even more thanks to [@Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).

**To 180 bytes:** -1 bytes thanks again to [@Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen), by replacing the `i!=1` with `i<2`.

**To 177 bytes:** Moved the whole "nonsense soup" line onto the same line as the `for` loop, thanks to [@des54321](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/111305/des54321)'s suggestion.

**To 146 bytes:** Some *major* byte-saving golfs thanks to [@ElPedro](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56555/elpedro).

**To 130 bytes:** More golfs by [@Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen), including replacing `\\` with `\`.

Comment: [181 bytes with some golfs](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwEEX3OcV0VklUxNhVITcJFEXTZhMlKqQYe/U0bRGy@zN/3mPm1/qcbBvjMGrQ1LAbga3sJd6xREACi9QI@8YNF4eyaaEnBx6MBdfZx0hN1XwZWArppTSV6OwAGsPec38olUhx1L8hJDyxWddzmrTF23PBsiMCblw3Z5OTmotsTuP/iZAkGJSqA7I4O2NXqmnDGDmzyHKb5Stj8QM) :) The `u,b` declaration is a single line to save a byte; the `if`/`else` are both single lines with `and`/`or` to save byes; and the `(i*2)-(x*2)-2` (for which you don't need the parenthesis) is `i*2+~x*2` to save some bytes (`~x` is `-x-1` btw).

Comment: One more small golf for -1: `s+(i!=1and f"|{u*i*2}|"or"|\\/|")` can be `s+(i<2and"|\\/|"or f"|{u*i*2}|")`

Comment: can shove the whole nonsense soup inside the for loop onto the end of the same line for [177 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwEEX3OcWQVSYqYuyqNDcJFEXTZhMlKqQYe/U0bRGyezN/3mfm1/qcbBvjMGrQzOCVwFb2kt5pSYESWKSmsG/ccHEomxZ6cuDBWHCdfYzMVA1el0J6KU0lOjuApmHvuT@USpo46t8QkpvELOs5S53F23OB2REBN66bs7AUzNy@hTQoVYfT/n8SKMbZGbsyzRpEcrLIuM34ghg/)

Comment: @des54321 Done. Thanks! It's funny watching the Try it online! link gradually shrink.

Comment: You can define `u="__"` and lose the `*2` each time you reference `u` for [172](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwEEX3OcUwqyQqYuxKmpsERNG02USJBlKMvXqqBcHd@8x/n5k/63uydUrDqEFTwxoCPu8lti3mCEhgkRph89zsyh5RTw4CGAuus6@RmqJizZLJIKUpRGcH0Bi3noddqc3v5R/jYR7a7dJzarjIvoELdisRcOPqnYUlo@Z5zmFUqoyXfX4RkaXZGbtSTSvGyMXixvWNH4ylHw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: `u,b="__"," ";s=f" {u*i}\n"` saves another 1 by avoiding an unneeded indent.

Comment: And assigning `b*x` to a variable will get it to [169](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwFET3OcXnr5KoiLGr2twkIIqmzSZKNGA19upWF4q7xzBvmP47fjqbb1vTatDUsCcBH9cSyxJjBCwGqREWz82qLBLQnYMJjAVX2XdLTZKx5yxrPhVDJCcpTSIq24DGsMyrUotf0x3C7u7ildacGi6i38QFuwoEXDt6Z2GIqHkdMxiUSsNpHh8Csq13xo5U04wxcrK4cX7jB2PbHw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Last one from me is to use list slicing for your return value for [166](https://tio.run/##Tc1BCoMwEIXhvacYZpVERdSulPQiTRFF02YTJSqkGnv1VBcVdx@P@ZnhM717nXvfdhIkUbQIYI4ajlWFEQKWI5cI68zUJjQGIHsDFpQGU@tXR1Sc0mLhDbPlGHLLuYqzWrcg0a3LJsQ6b8kOt7d7eK4NI4pl4deyjJ4HAZhumo2GMSTohEgcRkdx/HZIH@qePv1glJ6IJCmlwd/ZxfnFN0r9Dw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Knew it would go under 150 :-) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BCoMwFET3nuLzV/kxImpXlfQiRqRS02YTJSpYjb261ULB3YOZN9O9h1drs217NBo0M3QNYBS1xKpCgYB5LzXCMnKzKosB6NbBBMaCu9tnw0yU0HWWNZ/yPtybfplXpRZWc2Z4Gn4mnpIYqZikNFFarvGe@9@Qa4bRWehDhl6p2KM47OPHIxXmlpRb54wdmGYJUfDn9MTZiS9E2xc "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: After @ElPedro golfs everything can be put onto a single line and you can use a lambda for [134 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYzRCoIwFEDf@4pxn7Y5E2dPwfoRJ@Ko1Q2bIgoLZ7@@NAh8Ow/nnP49PjpXRKt0bJuXuTYExaSgrkEYBQTOFsg8cVy0gwTg@OzQUQthNtwvWs/UcIpcJh/PJRMTK71SmMpqyX5GWDPbDcQTdGRo3P1GMc0ZSygErbMAYntt/wCsxEtexX5AN1JLV@vwZ7njYscnxuIX).

Comment: [132 bytes](https://tio.run/##TczdCoIwGIDh865ifEf7M3F2FKwbcSKOWn1hU0RhoXbry4rAs/fg4e2ew631eXTaxKZ@2HNNUI4aqgqk1UDgaMXIUQDs7y166sD4ebI8LMZM1HKKXIlX4IrJkRVBa0xUuaRfMYNrexIIetLX/nqhmGSMCfpZGJPOIH@39b9aVuApK2PXox@oo6vc/VttOt/0gbH4Bg) actually with two more minor golfs: `f" {u*i}\n"` to `b+u*i+` for -1, and changing the positions of the `\n` a bit for another -1.

Comment: [130 bytes](https://tio.run/##TczdCoIwGIDh865ifEf7M3F2FKwbcSKOWn1hU0RhoXbry4rAs/fg4e2ew631eXTaxKZ@2HNNUI4aqgqk1UDgaMXIUQDs7y166sD4ebI8LGaillPkSrwCV0yOrAhaY6LKJf2CGVzbk0DQk7721wvFJGNM0M/BpDPI32u9r5QVeMrK2PXoB@roCnf/VpvON31gLL4B) by replacing both \\ with \ (apparently they don't have to be escaped in Python's strings depending on the character behind it).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - I guessed you'd be back! Thanks for finishing it off for me. Was busy this afternoon :) Didn't know that about the \\ in f-strings. Learned something new today. Thanks.

Comment: @ElPedro I didn't knew either tbh. Just noticed it worked when I tried it. ;) And I don't think it's just f-strings. The one in the tuple at the end isn't an f-string. Python might just be smart enough to know that `\/` and `\{` doesn't have to be escaped (I think).

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 49 bytes

```
1=[\_‛|\"|2≠[⇩ʁ(⁰Ifn\\Ȧ¤j)]‛\_⁰r:t⁰ẋ:£W\|vp¥p]vøṀ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJDIiwiIiwiMT1bXFxf4oCbfFxcXCJ8MuKJoFvih6nKgSjigbBJZm5cXFxcyKbCpGopXeKAm1xcX+KBsHI6dOKBsOG6izrCo1dcXHx2cMKlcF12w7jhuYAiLCIiLCI0Il0=)

Comment: Doesn't work, draws backslashes instead of slashes

Comment: @allxy Fixed and shavead off a couple more bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 107 bytes

```python
lambda n:[' '+(a:="__"*n)]+['|%s|'%[a," "*i+f'\{"_ "[i<n-2]*2*(n+~i)}/'+" "*i][i<n-(n>2)]for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TczNCsIwEATgu08RAmU3iT/YXqRYXyQNJaLRFd2W2ItYffVYKoi3YeZjukd/brnYdDGFqk5Xf9sfvODSggCDvqxk00jNyhkLQ3YfILN@LoXUZALUT9kIaWnLi9zpXCObN6nXCswk3LQg73LlQhsFCWIRPZ@OOB6mLhL3CDXD8tISY8BCKTWbfftf@AfrEaQP)

-20 by @emanresuA

Comment: You can save a bunch by outputting as a list of lines, which opens up a whole host of golfing oppurtunities - [107 bytes](https://tio.run/##TczNCsIwEATgu08RAmU3iT/YXqRYXyQNJaLRFd2W2ItYffVYKoi3YeZjukd/brnYdDGFqk5Xf9sfvODSggCDvqxk00jNyhkLQ3YfILN@LoXUZALUT9kIaWnLi9zpXCObN6nXCswk3LQg73LlQhsFCWIRPZ@OOB6mLhL3CDXD8tISY8BCKTWbfftf@AfrEaQP).

Answer (score 2):

## [Javascript](https://www.javascript.com/), <strike>181</strike> <strike>177</strike> 174 Bytes

Code is split into newlines for readability, see link for 174 byte string.

```javascript
c=n=>{
r=(d,n)=>d.repeat(n);
z='\n|';
b=r('_',n*2);
o=' '+b;
for(e=0;e<n-1;e++)y=r(' ',e),o+=z+y+'\\'+r(e!=n-2?' ':'_',n*2-2*(e+1))+'/'+y+'|';
o+=(n==1?z+'\\/|':z+b+'|');
return o;}
```

[Try me online.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY89bsJAEIXrcIpNNbuMDbELhBgGLmIpiu0BWbJm0cYUGHKSNBTQ5j65TXYlp37f-_t-qG_lfn-eh0O-_v1pWHl3DWzbTB3v2kWQk3wMVh2NDJXegGoOFt4h03npyDMYwJoOPljhN5Kt5gUJorskzEAmLvPII14QqgowYq-sebmP2maKycu5FSycQ1hCAmNL9FhlLvZj8i1vsBmxToqjIMM5qPH0Na1ep_ZeBtMZNgWZbssr6uKG6-yl8frpe1n0_mgb2zmDJt6oNObMJv__-z8)

- Saved 4 bytes pulling `\n|` into a variable `z`
- Saved 3 bytes pulling `r(' ',e)` into `y` every loop

I'm not too happy with my performance here, especially the implicit check I had to do to get the i=1 output working, but oh well.

Comment: Just so you know, readability doesn't matter in this case, so you can make it as unreadable as you like ;-)! The goal is to have it as golfed as possible.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `o`, 37 bytes

```
\_*:£ðpm,ċ[ɽ‹\\꘍ṫ\_+J↲¥J\|vpvøṀ⁋|‛|\m
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJvIiwiIiwiXFxfKjrCo8OwcG0sxItbyb3igLlcXFxc6piN4bmrXFxfK0rihrLCpUpcXHx2cHbDuOG5gOKBi3zigJt8XFxtIiwiIiwiNCJd)

```
\_*                                   # <input> copies of _
   :£                                 # Duplicate and set gregister
     ðpm,                             # Prepend a space and print mirrored
         ċ[                     |‛|\m # If it's 1, print `|\/|`, else:
           ɽ‹                         # 0...n-1
             \\꘍                      # For each, prepend that many spaces to an underscore
                ṫ   J                 # To the last...
                 \_+                  # Append an underscore
                     ↲                # Pad all of that to length n
                      ¥J              # Append the underscores that we stored in the register earlier
                        \|vp          # Prepend a | to each
                            vøṀ⁋      # Mirror and print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0 -a`, 98 bytes

```perl
say$".__ x$_,map{'
|',/@F/*($#a=$_-1)?__ x$_.'|':"@a\\".($_<"@F"-1?'  ':__)x("@F"-$_)."/@a|"}1..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoic2F5JFwiLl9fIHgkXyxtYXB7J1xufCcsL0BGLyooJCNhPSRfLTEpP19fIHgkXy4nfCc6XCJAYVxcXFxcIi4oJF88XCJARlwiLTE/JyAgJzpfXyl4KFwiQEZcIi0kXykuXCIvQGF8XCJ9MS4uJF8iLCJhcmdzIjoiLU01LjEwLjBcbi1hIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIxXG4yXG4zXG40XG4xMFxuMTEifQ==)

Currently on mobile (in a rainy field!) so I'll add an explanation later!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 68 bytes

```
ð'_IиJJÂJUX,I<F'|ðNи'\N>I<Qi'_ëð}IN-<·и'/ðNи'|JJ,}I2‹i"|\/|"ëXð'|:},
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Ab1eM8LO7y8Djd5hUboeNq4qdcc3uB3YYd6jJ@dp01gpnr84dWHN9R6@unaHNoOFNaHyNZ4eenUeho9atiZqVQTo1@jdHh1BNCsGqtanf//TQA)

Explanation:

```
ð              Push space
'_Iи           Push I underscores (I = input)
JJÂJ           Push reverse of that
UX,            Put that in X and print it
I<F            Loop from 1 to N-1 (N = index)
  '|           Push '|' (pipe)
  ðNи          Push N spaces
  '\           Push '\' (backslash)
  N>I<Qi'_     If N+1 == I-1, push _ (underscore)
    ëð}        Otherwise push space
  IN-<·и       Pop and repeat that by (I-N-1)*2
  '/           Push '/' (slash)
  ðNи          Push N spaces
  '|           Push '|' (pipe)
  JJ,          Join and print
}      
I2‹i"|\/|"     If I == 1, push '|\/|'
  ëXð'|:}      Otherwise, push X with spaces replaced with pipes
,              Print
```